# Keep cursor from moving to the next button when tab key pressed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a form with 3 pages. When the first page fills up the user goes to the next page by clicking the 'next' button.

**Intention:** If the user presses the <kbd>tab</kbd> key, a message shows, and the cursor remains in the 'next' button.

**Problem:** when I press the <kbd>tab</kbd> key the message shows and the cursor remains on the 'next' button. However, the 2nd time the <kbd>tab</kbd> key is pressed, the cursor goes to the next page.

Here is my code:

```
 <div class="next"><a class="next-button" href="#second">Next</a></div>

 $('.next-button').on("keyup", function(event) {
 if (event.which == 9) {
   alert('Click Next button to go to the next Page');
   return false;
}
});
```

Comment: can you create a fiddle? http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: What do you mean by course? Also, your JavaScript needs to be enclosed in `<script></script>` tags.

Comment: I edited the question to read 'cursor' instead of 'course'. Reya Mony, please offer clarification if this isn't what you meant.

Comment: Be very careful with this. Removing the proper functionality of the tab key will make your site non-navigable by users who (for whatever reason) don't or can't use a mouse. In the UK, this would be a breach of the disability discrimination act.

Comment: please check here https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/168659703/project2/Vastgoedwebsite-maken%20-%20Copy.html

Comment: @ReyaMony The first time the 'Next' button is in focus, a message should appear, and the next press of tab should actually click the 'Next' button? Is this what you want?

Comment: @Rao when user use tab then alert always show. But if press Enter or click next then user goes to next page.

Comment: oh, then you should be using a `confirm` box instead of `alert` so when the user is displayed a message, she can click 'ok' to confirm and go to next page.

Comment: @Rao if I'm understanding correctly, she doesn't want it to go to the next page at all. @ReyaMony have you tried substituting `keyup` with `keydown`?

Comment: `e.preventDefault()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see that in your example, when the second time the <kbd>tab</kbd> key is pressed the cursor falls into the first field of your 'second page'.  Maybe there's a more efficient way to approach this, but how about this?

```
 $('.next-button').on("keydown", function(event) {
     if (event.which == 9) {     
        alert('Click Next button to go to the next Page');
        this.focus();             
        return false;

    }
});
```

Notice that I'm forcing the focus back on the Next button.  My JSFiddle, of course, doesn't reflect the real functionality of your page, but this might give you an idea of how it would work:

http://jsfiddle.net/BBWxz/1/

If the second page still shows up even after focusing on the Next button, then you could add this to the code above, so the second page doesn't doesn't show at all.

```
$('.second-page').hide();
```

So basically, the code would look like this:

```
 $('.next-button').on("keydown", function(event) {
     if (event.which == 9) {     
        alert('Click Next button to go to the next Page');
        this.focus();
        $('.second-page').hide();
        return false;

     }
});
```

Kludgy? yes, but I think this will do what you want.